# beginner: django progress bar jquery (not for multipart forms)

Tags: jquery, python, django

Disclaimer: I am new to django and python but have Drupal programming experience.

I spent the last 3 hours searching for a simple way of integrating a jqueryui progress bar into my django (development server) site (running sqlite on localhost) where the bar is NOT showing file uploads but the progress of another python script (I need to transfer hundreds of photos from many SDCards to the localhost via the django web front-end). My web app already has a working jquery dialog box and I can properly issue and receive simple ajax requests ($.get...

So, my question is now about the approach. Should I use threads, a subprocess, sessions, or some combination? Any snippets (or complete demos's to help me along)?

If threads is the answer, I assume this is OK? http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201103/quick_and_dirty_multithreaded_django_dev_server.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like django-ztask or celery to do the background process.

The page that the user is on, should query a view for the progress % with ajax or maybe just reload itself and show an updated progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it realtime, you can use long-polling but there are too many things to do.

The brain dead simplest way to it should be using a separate process as worker and updating the process to a temporary file. (This file will only have 1 line, which is the percent of the progress).

Your view should simply fetch the file and read it and return to the client as it is. Since the information on the temporary file is one-line progress indicator(e.g. "79" for 79%), It is very easy to parse with Javascript.

Then on the browser, you can call your view via ajax get request every 5 second and update the progress bar.